# Apply function to each n rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas df col which looks like the following:

```
0           0.286
1           0.240
2           0.335
3           0.397
2430       38.580
2431       38.650
2432       38.630
2433       38.170
6007       72.960
6008       71.250
6009       70.370
6010       70.460 ...
```

I would like to output a `new_col` with the % change from the initial value, resetting every fourth value, then a final 4 line output which takes the average of every fourth value in the `new_col`.

Expected output `new_col`:

```
0.00
-16.08
17.13
38.81
0.00
0.18
0.13
-1.06
0.00
-2.34
-3.55
-3.43
```

`avg_col`

```
0.00
-6.08
4.57
11.44
```

Comment: OK, where is your code ? what is your error ?

Comment: Also share expected output for something non-trivial as this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `new_col` by grouping every 4 lines:

```
df['new_col'] = df.groupby(df.index//4)[1].apply(lambda x: (x-x.iloc[0])/x.iloc[0]*100).reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

Or to avoid the `.groupby.apply` perhaps transform and then do the calculation (might be faster for large Frames)

```
df['new_col'] = df.groupby(df.index//4)[1].transform('first')
df['new_col'] = (df[1] - df.new_col)/df.new_col*100
```

#### Output `df`:

```
       0       1    new_col
0      0   0.286   0.000000
1      1   0.240 -16.083916
2      2   0.335  17.132867
3      3   0.397  38.811189
4   2430  38.580   0.000000
5   2431  38.650   0.181441
6   2432  38.630   0.129601
7   2433  38.170  -1.062727
8   6007  72.960   0.000000
9   6008  71.250  -2.343750
10  6009  70.370  -3.549890
11  6010  70.460  -3.426535
```

Get the average by grouping by the division remainder:

```
df.groupby(df.index%4).new_col.mean()

0     0.000000
1    -6.082075
2     4.570859
3    11.440642
Name: new_col, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I appreciate very clever use of `df.groupby(df.index//4)`

Comment: Yes, and if for some reason your index is not a `RangeIndex` just use `.reset_index` to make it one, so grouping every 4 lines always works.

Comment: when I run the line `df['new_col'] = df.groupby(df.index//4)[1].transform('first')` on my df it produces a strange result

`0.286
0.286
0.286
0.286
38.580`
**38.580**
**38.630**
`38.630`
**72.960**
**71.250**
`71.250
71.250`

Comment: @W.R. That is the expected result for that line. The whole point is to create a 'dummy' value which we can then use to calculate the percent changed from the first value of the group as a vectorized calculation. After we create that value, then the second line correctly calculates the percentage change. `.groupby.apply` can tend to be slow for many groups. I suspect that second method will be significantly faster than the first, though the calculation is split across 2 lines.

Comment: ok, however when running both lines I get the result 
`0.000000
 -16.083916
  17.132867
   38.811189
 0.000000
 0.181441
0.000000
-1.190784
 0.000000
 0.000000
 -1.235088
 -1.108772`

Comment: Yes, the above is the output I get when running both lines