# Python "looping" with apply() but skipping 150 lines

Tags: python, loops, append

I have read all these answers saying not to use for loops with iterrows and never modify something I am iteration over, so I am trying to use apply with the lambda but I don’t totally get it.
I want to “loop over” the dataframe and on every 150 row I want to change the gender to the opposite of what it is.
So if the colum with heading “gender” is “Female”, I will change it to “Male”. If it wasn’t “Female” (then it was male) and I then want to change it to Female.

Dataframe looks like this:

```
age gender income
40  Female 20000
42  Male   30000
45  Female 40000
```

This is some of what I have tried.

```
new_large_df.apply(
    lambda row:
            row.gender == "Female",
            row.gender == "Male",
            row.gender == "Female",
        
    axis=1
    row + 150
)
```

updated, after the suggestion (just used 2 instead of 150 as it easier to check)

```
new_large_df.groupby(new_large_df.index//2)[gender].apply(
    lambda row:
            row.gender == "Female",
            row.gender == "Male",
            row.gender == "Female",
        
    axis=1
)
```

Now instead I get the error that `"gender" is not defined`. Should it not pick it up when using index?

How do I write something that goes over the dataFrame and changes values of gender on every 150 line?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apply function to each n rows pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54557262/apply-function-to-each-n-rows-pandas)

Comment: @deadshot It did not answer my question totally, but got me a little bit further on the way. See update, I get an error, that I can't figuare out.